# what is the type of variables defined in enum?

Tags: scala, enums

I'm new in scala, and while trying to understand below code, found lot of doubts. Please help me to understand this

There is one scala file named as `MyEnums.scala`, and code present within it as follow

```
object AllEnums extends Enumeration {

  type Enums = Value
  val one,two,three = Value

  def getAllValues() : String = values.mkString(",")

}
```

I'm new in scala, also bit confused same enumeration logic in Java too.  Trying to understand how enum defined here.

1. Is `AllEnums` is a object of class `MyEnums.scala` ?
2. If `1` point is correct that means, `MyEnums.scala` extending class `MyEnums.scala` ?
3. `type Enums = Value`, `Value` is type in scala, what's a real significance of it and what this statement `type Enums = Value` is doing  in code ?
4. `val one,two,three = Value`, In this statment Is `= Value` means the values assigned to `val one,two,three` are of type `Value` ?
5. `val one,two,three`, Are these instance variables of class `MyEnums.scala`, whic is nothing but of `Enumeration` Type ?
6. what's a type of these `val`s `one,two,three` ? Assigning values to these are of `Value` type, but is there any type of these variables itself `one,two,three` ?

Comment: Forget the enumeration in scala2, just using `enum` in scala3 or `case object` in scala2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is AllEnums is a object of class MyEnums.scala ?

No

> If 1 point is correct that means, MyEnums.scala extending class MyEnums.scala ?

No

> type Enums = Value, Value is type in scala, what's a real significance of it and what this statement type Enums = Value is doing in code ?

`type Enums = Value` makes `Enums` an alias of `Value`.
As for "significance" of it, I am not sure how to answer that. What is the "real significance" of `Boolean`?

> val one,two,three = Value, In this statment Is = Value means the values assigned to val one,two,three are of type Value ?

Yes

> val one,two,three, Are these instance variables of class MyEnums.scala, whic is nothing but of Enumeration Type ?

`MyEnums.scala` is a file, not a class.
`one, two, three` are members of `AllEnums`, and it certainly is not "nothing".

> what's a type of these vals one,two,three ?

It is `Value` as you said yourself above. Or `Enums`, which is the same as. `Value`.

> Assigning values to these are of Value type, but is there any type of
> these variables itself one,two,three ?

Yes. `Value`.

Comment: what if I dont specify <<type Enums = Value>>, then what would be the type of one, two and three ? Is it AllDimensions ? How would i assign values to all enums without specifying Value alias ?

Comment: The type is `Value`. If you say `type Enums = Value`, then you can also refer to it as `Enums`